# Pipfile.lock (d67565) out of date, updating to (4f9dd2)

Tags: django

Can somoene explain why i get this error Pipfile.lock (d67565) out of date, updating to (4f9dd2)…when i try to install packages using pipenv .Altoough i have used pipenv install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWaUJ.png)

Comment: The main reason behind updation is that whenever you install a module or app its raw record is being kept by pipfile. Now why so? Beacuse it helps to know which version of packages are being used in a project to make that project work perfectly and the pipfile lock prevents that module or app to get updated automatically (mean locks your application version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I noticed that it happens due to following reasons,

when you install a new app from terminal using pipenv.
secondly when you run pipenv shell command again after closing your project,
also when you make some changes in your pipfile, and lastly when you deploy your project on somthing like heroku.